# Why does this print one input 7 times once executed, rather than get input 7 times?

Tags: python-3.x, input, while-loop, infinite-loop, increment

Earlier when I tested a little bit I could input each time, but now it won't. It's purpose is to see who gets the highest score per round, and decide a winner at the end.
I've gone through my coursework and done a lot googling but can't find the answer. I've been at it for a good few hours now and can't figure it out. I've tried ranges, lists etc, I keep getting infinite loops and can't iterate, get input and repeat.
I even done some single line loops (wouldn't make a difference, just trying anything!) but found it easier to have it line by line while I'm figuring it out. Just set this account up to get some help please.

Where am I going wrong?
Edit: I'm not concerned about strings or floats being added and bugs from that. This is purely integers so it's assumed that's what will be entered.

```
player_one = 0
player_two = 0


#ask player-one for input
score_one = input("Player one, what is your score?")

#ask player_2 for input
score_two = input("Player two, what is your score?")

#compare who has the highest score and add to counter


while player_one != 7 or player_two != 7 is True:  
    if score_one > score_two:
        print("Player 1 wins the round with ", score_one, "beating Player 2 with", score_two)
        player_one += 1
        
    elif score_two > score_one:
        print("Player 2 wins the round with ", score_two, "beating Player 1 with", score_one)
        player_two += 1
        
    else:
        score_one == score_two
        print("This round has ended in a draw.")
        player_one += 1
        player_two += 1
        
  #print winner, loser, scores and also if draw  

    if player_one == 7:
        print("The game has ended with Player 1 winning by ", player_one, "to Player 2's", player-two)
        break
    elif player_two == 7:
        print("The game has ended with Player 2 winning by ", player_two, "to Player 1's", player_one)
        break
    while player_one == 7 and player_two == 7:
        print("DING DING it's a draw.")
        break
```

Comment: Your inputs are outside the while loop, so `score_one` and `score_two` never change when you're inside the while loop. Try moving the inputs inside the while loop (also, the third-to-last line in your code sample should probably be `elif` instead of `while`)

Comment: sidenote: the `is True` is redundant.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy thanks, that did the trick. I have some other issues now with it but I'll figure it out. The 'while' was a remnant of my tinkering from today, as was 'is True' Charchit, thanks for pointing out, thought I had it cleaned up.